# Convert keys into days in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash that will have keys in number seprated by _ like this `49_168`.
Now i want to convert these keys into a hours .if the keys is greater than `48` then i have to convert the whole key in hours like `49_168` this key will became `"From 3 to 7 days"`

**My Hash**

```
{
 '49_168' => {

               'Amt' => "100"
             },
 '169_720' => {
                'Amt' => "100"
              },
 '2_48' => {
            'Amt' => "100"
           },
 '721_-' => {
              'Amt' => "100"
            }
}
```

What i was trying is "

```
@timearray = split (/-/,$time_keys);
    if(@timearray[0] > 48){
        $desc .= "From ".ceil(@timearray[0]/24);
    }
    if(@timearray[1] > 48){
        $desc .= "To ".ceil(@timearray[1]/24)."days";
    }
```

In case of `-` we have to show blank value.
How can we do this please help me

**Desired output**

```
'49_168' = "3days to 7 days"     
'169_720' ="8 days to 30 days"
'2_48' =""
'721_-' = "31 days onwards" // Incase after _ we will get - then we will put onwards
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: @simbabque i have updated the question but it is not working properly

Comment: Can you also specify the desired output for all cases please? You are talking about _hours_ in the question but the title says _days_ and the target you show has _days_ for if it's greater than 48. What about the smaller one?

Comment: @simbabque i have updated the question please check for the smaller ones we will not do any thing

Comment: What happens in case of `2_49`?

Comment: then we have to show from 2 hours to 3 days

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79620/discussion-between-gaurav-and-simbabque).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing that in the chat, we came up with this. I created a unit test to cover all the cases that you named in the comments of the question.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More 'no_plan';
my %input = (
    '49_168'  => "3 days to 7 days",
    '169_720' => "8 days to 30 days",
    '2_48'    => '',
    '721_-'   => "31 days onwards",
    '2_49'    => "from 2 hours to 3 days",
);

while ( my ( $input, $desired_output ) = each %input ) {
    is convert_to_day_string($input), $desired_output, 
      qq{"$input" becomes "$desired_output"};
}
```

Then we can build the function `convert_to_day_string` as follows.

```
use POSIX 'ceil';

sub convert_to_day_string {
    my ($period) = @_;

    my ( $from, $to ) = split /_/, $period;

    my $from_string;
    if ( $from < 49 ) {

        # from is in hours
        $from_string = sprintf 'from %d hours', $from;
    }
    else {
        # from is in days
        $from_string = sprintf '%d days', ceil( $from / 24 );
    }

    my $to_string;
    if ( $to =~ m/-/ ) {

        # to is indefinite
        $to_string = ' onwards';
    }
    else {
        # to is too small, abort
        return q{} if $to < 49;

        # to is in days
        $to_string = sprintf ' to %d days', ceil( $to / 24 );
    }

    return $from_string . $to_string;
}
```

I chose to be extra verbose instead of making it idiomatic because I think the extra legibility will help you.

---

My advice in a case like this:

- Always `use strict` and `use warnings`, they help you spot mistakes
- If there are several kinds of output, write a test. It helps you not only writing the code, but also coming back later if you need to change it. See [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More) for more information on that.
- In terms of Stack Overflow, always include your code and sample input/output in your queston so others can actually help and don't have to ask for that stuff.